# Controlling a laser rangefinder via the raspberry pi

Tags: hardware, serial, i2c

First, a disclaimer that I am an electronics newbie. I got my hands on a laser rangefinder which looks very similar to this:
[image]

On the top left corner, there are two sets of pins. The first set has these four:

1. GND
2. CLK
3. DIO
4. 3V3

The second one has three:

1. RX
2. TX
3. GND

What I want to do is control the rangefinder from my raspberry pi 4. Basically, I'd like to programmatically trigger a measurement and then read the result. I am okay with Python but I am not sure how to wire this to my pi.

Based on some googling I think the first set of pins is for I²C and the second is for serial/TTL communication. [I also found this blog](https://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-LiDAR-using-the-laser-rangefinder-Uni-T-UT3/) where a weaker rangefinder was connected to an Arduino using the TX, RX and GND pins so I hope it's possible to do something similar on the raspberry pi.

How would I proceed with this? I'd like to use the same pins but I don't know where to connect them to, nor which commands to give (though I assume I would use a library [such as this](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/)).

Comment: You NEED to find the specifications of the device you want to use. Then, if you need help  implementing a solution ask specific questions. As this Question stands the best you could hope for is lots of idle speculation.

Comment: Are you a poor hobbyist like me, playing only cheap stuff? If yes, I would recommend the I2C or UART interface toys such as this: https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32960610502.html?spm=a2g0w.search0302.3.44.4344283azpHwrL&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=ea54bbe2-a7b2-4e8b-bf97-27651ef01749&algo_expid=ea54bbe2-a7b2-4e8b-bf97-27651ef01749-6. If you are an electronics newbie, I would recommend Serial, rather than I2C, which is bit tricky to handle.

Comment: You might also like to read my answer to the following question to know more about LIDARs: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/102375/controlling-5-lidars-using-raspberry-pi

Comment: @Milliways I found a [specification](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32885257115.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.5ead56e4IYp85e&algo_pvid=239f8c66-6483-4600-863a-b0799ceee9c9&algo_expid=239f8c66-6483-4600-863a-b0799ceee9c9-12&btsid=0ab6f82315881922383636850e408c&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) which might apply on my device as well. It works by TTL. I guess I could get a TTL to USB adapter and try it out on my desktop?

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks a lot for the links and info. However, I need a long range rangefinder (at least 600m) and I have not found anything which can easily be connected to a raspberry pi.

Comment: Hi @Theo, You laser range finder: "AliExpress serial/TTL interface 600/1000/1500m laser rangefinder module (H600A/H1000A/H1500A)- US$120": https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32885257115.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.5ead56e4IYp85e&algo_pvid=239f8c66-6483-4600-863a-b0799ceee9c9&algo_expid=239f8c66-
6483-4600-863a-b0799ceee9c9-12&btsid=0ab6f82315881922383636850e408c&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_ looks OK.

Comment: It uses TTL/serial so it should be easy to use. The product sheet uses SSCOMS terminal emulator to do the measurements. Usually any similar standard terminal emulators such as puTTY, miniCom, Rpi's CuteCom can be used. Usually you send AT Commands, such as "AT", "RESET“，"START" etc and the thing will return text messages such as "1234m" etc. To use Rpi python serial to send AT commands and receive text responses is also very easy, you can easily find newbie friendly tutorials to do it. You can google the toy's  "English Manual" first, just to make sure, before you invest you US120: )